# How connect Middleware and redux-persis

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage, jsx

How can I connect Middleware and redux-persis?
Below is my index.js and store.js, I don't know how right can I cinnect them.
Now I have an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"
How can I fix it?
Thank you!

store

```
const persistConfig ={
    key: 'root',
    storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, Reducer);
const persistor = persistStore(store);


const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window === 'object' &&
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?   
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
    }) : compose;


const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
)

export {store, persistor};
```

index.js

```
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {store, persistor} from "./Store/store.js";
import {PersistGate} from "redux-persist/integration/react";

const app =(
    <Provider store={store} >
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Do you have a better stacktrace for the uncaught typeerror?

Comment: persistStore.js?2a8a:114 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined
    at Object.persist (persistStore.js?2a8a:114)
    at persistStore (persistStore.js?2a8a:123)
    at eval (store.js?40cf:14)
    at Module../src/Store/store.js (main.js:1562)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at eval (index.js?b635:1)
    at Module../src/index.js (main.js:1909)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at Object.0 (main.js:1932)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)    This is all text of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to persist the store before you create it. I would suggest passing in a preloaded state:

```js
const persistConfig ={
    key: 'root',
    storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, Reducer);
const preloadedState = {
  // Fill out accordingly
}

const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window === 'object' &&
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?   
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
    }) : compose;


const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    preloadedState,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
)

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export {store, persistor};
```